# Get facebook graph api base url from ios sdk

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to get the graph api base url (i.e. graph.facebook.com/v2.0/) from the facebook ios sdk? 
What i want to do is get the profile img and i don't want to hard code the url since if the version changes again i have to update it, so i want to get it from the sdk so it updates automatically.

P.S. I don't want to make a call for the img url either and i know the profile url comes with each friend when you get them but it's too much work to use those so it's not an option at this point